# Is there a way to add a shared axis title on a subplot?

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to create a 2x2 subplot, with both plots in each column having the same y-axis title, like this :

[image: Dummy plot with same yaxis titles]

i.e. one 'title' (here called annotations, cf. later) for the left column (blue+green) and one for the right column (yellow+red).

I can easily have a yaxis title for each plot but I'm stumped as to making shared ones.
I tried using annotations, like this (this is the code used to render the plot shown above) :

```r
if (!require("plotly")) install.packages("plotly")
library(plotly)

group <- c("a", "b", "c")
values <- c(0, 5, 10)
df <- data.frame(group, values)
plot <- df %>% 
  plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~group, y = ~values, type = "scatter", mode = "line") %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(ticks = "outside"), xaxis = list(showline = TRUE))
plot

subdf1 <- subplot(plot, plot, nrows = 1, margin = 0.06)
subdf2 <- subplot(plot, plot, nrows = 1, margin = 0.06)
subdf <- subplot(subdf1, subdf2, nrows = 2, margin = 0.06) %>% 
  layout(annotations = list(list(x = -0.1, y = 0.5, text = "<b>First annotation</b>", xref = "paper", yref = "paper", xanchor = "center", yanchor = "center", showarrow = FALSE, textangle = -90, font = list(color = "black", size = 16)), 
list(x = 0.48, y = 0.5, text = "<b>Second annotation</b>", xref = "paper", yref = "paper", xanchor = "center", yanchor = "center", showarrow = FALSE, textangle = -90, font = list(color = "black", size = 16))))
subdf
```

My main gripe with this method is that when the plot is resized, the annotations (mainly the first one, in the negative range for x-axis placement) move around the x-axis.

Same plot but wider : [image]

I used `xref = "paper"` as I thought it meant the whole plot area i.e. the whole white background, but in such case, my annotation wouldn't disappear (and wouldn't be in negatives, but I'm possibly not thinking about this the right way). I did try using `xref = x` but it won't go into negatives and instead just push the data to the right.

So all in all, two questions :

- Is there a native way to have a shared axis title for subplots?
- If not, is there a way to make sure that my annotations stay in the same relative place as the plots and axes when resizing the subplot?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate title in each `layout` of both `subplots` and combine them using `titleY` like this:

```r
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

group <- c("a", "b", "c")
values <- c(0, 5, 10)
df <- data.frame(group, values)
plot <- df %>% 
  plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~group, y = ~values, type = "scatter", mode = "line") %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(ticks = "outside"), xaxis = list(showline = TRUE))

subdf1 <- subplot(plot, plot, nrows = 1) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = "First annotation"))
subdf2 <- subplot(plot, plot, nrows = 1) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = "Second annotation"))
subdf <- subplot(subdf1, subdf2, nrows = 2, titleY = TRUE)  
subdf
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Edit**

Change `margin` in `layout`:

```r
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

group <- c("a", "b", "c")
values <- c(0, 5, 10)
df <- data.frame(group, values)
plot <- df %>% 
  plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~group, y = ~values, type = "scatter", mode = "line") %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(ticks = "outside"), xaxis = list(showline = TRUE))

subdf1 <- subplot(plot, plot, nrows = 1, margin = 0.06)
subdf2 <- subplot(plot, plot, nrows = 1, margin = 0.06)
subdf <- subplot(subdf1, subdf2, nrows = 2, margin = 0.06) %>% 
  layout(margin = 0.01,
         annotations = list(list(x = -0.1, y = 0.5, text = "<b>First annotation</b>", xref = "paper", yref = "paper", xanchor = "center", yanchor = "center", showarrow = FALSE, textangle = -90, font = list(color = "black", size = 16)), 
                            list(x = 0.48, y = 0.5, text = "<b>Second annotation</b>", xref = "paper", yref = "paper", xanchor = "center", yanchor = "center", showarrow = FALSE, textangle = -90, font = list(color = "black", size = 16))))
subdf
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I'll keep the `titleY` argument in mind, although it's not exactly the output I'm trying to get. What I'm trying to do is replicate the position of my two annotations in the first plot : one title on the left pertaining to the blue and green plots, and one between both columns pertaining to the yellow and red plots.

Comment: Hi @Throe, please check edited answer! you can use margin in layout.

Comment: Thanks @Quinten for the edit. To be honest I have trouble seeing what's the difference between your plot and the first one in my question. What I mean is, when I resize the plot the annotations (mainly the first one) still move along the x-axis. My main goal here, if there isn't a native way to add group titles, is to make sure that my annotations stay in place however I resize my plot. I'm thinking the solution might lie with `xref` and I'm not using the right reference for my coordinates ?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't tied to using plotly, this can be done in a straightforward way using faceting in ggplot. It may require some rearranging of your data into tidy format but gives some serious flexibility while plotting!

```
library(ggplot2)

group <- c("a", "b", "c")
values <- c(0, 5, 10)
df <- data.frame(group, values)

df <- data.frame(group = rep(c('a','b','c'), 4),
                 values = rep(c(0,5,10), 4),
                 facet = rep(c('W','X','Y','Z'), each = 3))

ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = values, colour = facet, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.1) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  facet_wrap(~facet) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = 'Shared X axis title', y = 'Shared Y axis title', colour = 'Traces') + 
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not constrained to Plotly per se, and `ggplot` has nice features such as this one I'm trying to replicate, I'm mostly trying to see what can and can't be done while making subplots with Plotly. But thanks for the suggestion !